# How to make an AJAX call with Confirm in lift?

Tags: ajax, lift

I'm new to lift, and want to implement following in my project:

There is a "delete" link in the page, when user clicks it, there will be a confirmation with text "are you sure to delete?". If user clicks on "yes", it will make an AJAX call to delete something on the server side, then show a notice "Operation complete", and after 3 seconds, the page will be reloaded.

How to implement this in lift? I have searched a lot, but not found an correct example.

I can only do this for now:

```
SHtml.a( ()=>Confirm("are you sure to delete", ???), "delete" )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the `SHtml.ajaxInvoke` in conjunction with `JsCmds.Confirm`. It will create a server side function and return a tuple with the functionId and `JsCmd`. So, something like this should do what you are looking to do:

```
SHtml.a( () => {
  JsCmds.Confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?", {
    SHtml.ajaxInvoke(() => {
      //Logic here to delete

      S.notice("Operation complete")
      JsCmds.After(3 seconds, JsCmds.Reload) //or whatever javascript response you want, e.g. JsCmds.Noop 
    })._2
  })
}, "delete")
```

In the above - clicking on the link will trigger the confirmation. If you select OK, then it will issue an ajax call to your function and display a notice. You can use that in any of the `SHtml` items that require a `JsCmd`.

If you want to have the page redirect after a timeout, you can just write a client-side javascript function to do what you need and use `JsCmds.Run` to call it.

Comment: Yes, that's the trick to get it working.:)

BTW, `._2` could be replaced with `.cmd`

Answer (score 0):

Using [reactive-web](http://reactive-web.tk):

```
            confirm("Are you sure you want to do that?") {
              case true =>
                // handle yes, if so desired
              case false =>
                // handle no, if so desired
            }
```

See the scaladocs: http://reactive-web.tk/reactive-web-api/#reactive.web.package

Comment: Note that any javascript you send to the browser from the thread of the ajax request that handles the confirm response (like any ajax request), will automatically be sent back as the body of the ajax response; you don't have to concern yourself with such details.